# setting a legend matching the colours in pyplot.scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose my data is organized in the following way:

```
x_values = [6.2, 3.6, 7.3, 3.2, 2.7]
y_values = [1.5, 3.2, 5.4, 3.1, 2.8]
colours = [1, 1, 0, 1, -1]
labels = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c"]
```

I want to make a scatterplot with this:

```
axis = plt.gca()
axis.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=colours)
```

I want a legend with 3 categories: "a", "b" and "c".

Can I use the `labels` list to make this legend, given that the categories in this list match the order of the points in the `colours` list?

Do I need to run the `scatter` command separately for each category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a colormap you can create a legend entry for each unique entry in the `colors` list as shown below. This approach works well for any number of values. The legend handles are the markers of a `plot`, such that they match with the scatter points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [6.2, 3.6, 7.3, 3.2, 2.7]
y_values = [1.5, 3.2, 5.4, 3.1, 2.8]
colors = [1, 1, 0, 1, -1]
labels = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c"]
clset = set(zip(colors, labels))

ax = plt.gca()
sc = ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=colors, cmap="brg")

handles = [plt.plot([],color=sc.get_cmap()(sc.norm(c)),ls="", marker="o")[0] for c,l in clset ]
labels = [l for c,l in clset]
ax.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it necessary to manually use this normalization to set the colour in `plot`? Aren't the colour determination mechanisms the same in `scatter` and `plot`?
It's been several years I occasionally use matplotlib, and I keep being confused.

Comment: You have one `scatter` but three `plot`s. So while the scatter would know the normalization, each individual plots wouldn't know about it. But you are correct in the sense that we don't need to set the normalization manually, but can instead reuse the scatter's normalization. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a remark, not exactly answering the question:

If use "seaborn" it would be EXACTLY ONE LINE:

```
import seaborn as sns 
x_values = [6.2, 3.6, 7.3, 3.2, 2.7]
y_values = [1.5, 3.2, 5.4, 3.1, 2.8]
#colors = [1, 1, 0, 1, -1]
labels = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c"]
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=x_values, y=y_values, hue=labels)
```

[image]

PS

But the question is about matplotlib, so.
We have answers above, also one might look at:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html
Subsection: "Automated legend creation".

However I feel not easy to modify those examples to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make your own legend as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

x_values = [6.2, 3.6, 7.3, 3.2, 2.7]
y_values = [1.5, 3.2, 5.4, 3.1, 2.8]

a = 'red'
b = 'blue'
c = 'yellow'

colours = [a, a, b, a, c]
labels = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c"]

axis = plt.gca()
axis.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=colours)

# Create a legend
handles = [mpatches.Patch(color=colour, label=label) for label, colour in [('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c)]]
plt.legend(handles=handles, loc=2, frameon=True)

plt.show()
```

Which would look like:

[image: plot with legend]

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer, but can't find the "handles" keyword in the help of `plt.legend`. How does it work? I guess that a "handle", in this context, is something drawing the graphical part of a legend entry (what the help calls a "legend artist"). Am I correct ?

Comment: Quite a few of the matplotlib function pass on any unknown keywords to a sub function to deal with, but this [link](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) should help.